# Spatial Clustering and ID Assignment for Roadside Pipes - ArcMap

Tags: arcmap

I have a group of pipes and IDs based on how they were surveyed, like this:

[image]

What I need to do is to group them and create new IDs based on their location, following the logic for example that some of them are on one side of the road and some on the other side.

The expected output should be like this:

[image]

My idea would be to group the pipes that are parallel and in contact.
But I'm sure there's a better solution for this.